# Error Code C01 on Maax Hydromax jetted tub

Tags: electrical, plumbing, bathtub, jetted

I have a Maax HydroMax jetted tub about 20 years old.  It gets a C01 error code when trying to turn on the jets. The pump runs for a second or less and then shuts off.

I have the install and operations manuals but they are fairly generic and don't specify a model number.  I looked all over the tub and couldn't fine one. There is very little information on the web about this. The only things I found was the generic "check your breakers for tripping" and one post about the ribbon cables attaching the controls were loose. I managed to get to them and wiggle and they seemed OK, but hard to tell.  Access is very poor.

Any ideas at all?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: No.  It's still not working. Hard to get a tech up there because it's a pretty remote area.

Answer (score 1):

Most tubs have a flow sensor that must be made to turn the heat on. I have had these sensors fail and cause the same problem but had no error code as mine was even older. The sensor or switch was on the length of pipe (metal) where the heater was it closed when the pump was running and opened when the pump was not running , this was the safety so the heat could not turn on if the pump was not running.  Mine screwed in in that area and had 2 wires connecting it, to check it measuring voltage should show the control voltage mine was 120v yours could be 24v turn the pump on and the switch should close with the pump running if no change that will probably be the problem. To see put the 2 wires from the switch together and the pumps will keep running, don’t leave it jumped because if the pumps are not running and the heater turns on it could damage the heater and water jack possibly even more damage than that.

Comment: Thanks so much Ed Beal for responding. I was hoping you would. What you said makes sense, but my jetted tub doesn't have a heater so it probably doesn't apply here. When I first starting diagnosing this, it had both  C01 and E06 error codes.  There was no access panel (STUPID) so I cut one in.  I found one of the ribbon cables end dangling. At first I thought it might have been for the heater that wasn't installed, but I took a picture of the end of the pump with my cell phone (very poor access), and found an empty multipin jack.  I managed by braille to reconnect it and the E06 err went away.

Comment: ...ran out of space.   I still think you are probably partially right in that there is a flow sensor not working right.   Frustrating problem.  Very little info.  One post mentioned poor connections on the LV ribbon cables.  But access is so poor it's hard to get to.   I'll probably have to enlarge the access even more.

Comment: I used to get parts at Jameco electronics they have or used to have the parts for ribbon cables (if it is failing a possibility). I was searching hot tubs , will look more for jetted bath tubs. is there a timer function where you can set the time? The jetted baths I have had were dumb only one had a heater but it had a pressure switch maybe the same one that the hot tubs used. Are there any names , numbers on the controller board? Some times manufacturers use a controller made by a different company any info on the board may help us find more info on the error code.

Comment: I'll get you as much info as I can later tomorrow.  I hope to get up to Crystal Mtn. tomorrow and get some skiing in during the day !:-)

Comment: I looked further all the Maax controllers I found were “Coleman”  back to the early 90’s , i did find a list of all tubs error controls that had CE01 as stuck touch pad button , other than that all the o1 errors were low flow and high temp.

Comment: Thanks for your research Ed Beal. Much appreciated. I'll see if I can find a repair tech to try and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

My repair tech got this from MAAX. Apparently the configuration code needs to be set to your unique tub configuration.

1. Hold the timer button until configuration code C01 appears
2. Use the "tornado" and "star" buttons as + and - to select the desired configuration
3. Press the time button to confirm the configuration.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1njTkOslWk
Also helpful.
Another and differing configuration chart at the end of his video.
He also talks about "Calibrating" the unit.